# django how to set background colour in html based on context

Tags: django

I am trying to change the background colour in a django project based on some information sent via the context

```
body base {
}

body alert {
    background-color: #FCFF33;
}

def check_alert() -> bool:
    return ...

def index(request):
    template = 'proj/index.html'
    ...
    context['alert'] = check_alert()
    return render(request, template, context)
```

How can I select the body class in the proj.html based on the field alert in

html looks like

```
{% load static %}
<html>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/proj.css' %}" />
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

I am wondering there is a solution like

```
<html>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/proj.css' %}" />
    <body class={% alert %}>  
    ...
```

and changing my view.py

```
context['alert'] = 'alert' if check_alert() else 'base'
```

EDIT:
When trying art06's solution, I realized that my template would not take any format for the body. Even If I dont class it and just have a simple css

```
body {
     background-color: #FFD9D9;
}
```

Any suggestions why that is?
Other formats in that css for example for tables created via

```
{% render_table table%}
```

are implemented correctly based on the css content.

Comment: `.css` and `.js` files are static, you can't change them from within a request. What you can do is use inline styles in your template, but they aren't considered a good practice ... IMHO, if the only style you're changing is the background color you can have it as an inline style, but if are changing a lot of things, keep them in classes and  only choose the right class at the template rendering time.

Comment: do you have an example for what you mean with inline style?

Comment: At your template `<body style="background-color: {{ color }}">`

Comment: What’s $base-spacing-unit?

Answer (score 0):

**Css**

```
body.alert{...}
body.base{...}
```

**Template**

```
<body class="{{alert}} ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it is promising, but I just realize my template does not use any css info I provide for body. even a blank one if I dont set a class. So there seems to be another problem I can't isolate yet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference alert....Reference it like {{alert}} instead of {% alert %}.